# Badges formatting is not proper when searched for a badge

Tags: bug, badges

When I search an badge its formatting is not proper. For reference-

[image]

[image]

Tested On Chrome and Edge in Windows 10

Comment: What would the proper formatting be?

Comment: Already reported: ["Select your next badge" modal displays badges with incorrect width and positioning](/q/367433/289905).